# combine 2 Selects in one

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query in mysql which work perfect.

```
        $result =mysql_query("
            SELECT a.IDN, c.Name_F, c.Name_L, d.Url_photo, 
                    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                        FROM Messages AS e
                        WHERE   e.IDN = a.IDN               
                    ) AS mes_new ,
                    ( SELECT LEFT(s.Messages,25)
                        FROM Messages AS s
                        WHERE s.Time= (SELECT MAX(k.Time)
                        FROM Messages AS k
                        WHERE k.IDN = a.IDN)

                    ) AS latest 
            FROM offers AS a 
                    LEFT JOIN info AS c
                ON a.IDN = c.IDN
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN photos AS d
                ON c.IDN = d.IDN AND d.Flag_av='1'

            Where a.IDN_with='$IDN' AND a.Status='2'    
        ");
```

But I have also one IDN and need to make also a similar another Select. Something like that:

```
            $result =mysql_query("
            SELECT a.IDN, c.Name_F, c.Name_L, d.Url_photo, 
                    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                        FROM Messages AS e
                        WHERE   e.IDN = a.IDN               
                    ) AS mes_new ,
                    ( SELECT LEFT(s.Messages,25)
                        FROM Messages AS s
                        WHERE s.Time= (SELECT MAX(k.Time)
                        FROM Messages AS k
                        WHERE k.IDN = a.IDN)

                    ) AS latest 
            FROM users AS a 
                    LEFT JOIN info AS c
                ON a.IDN = c.IDN
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN photos AS d
                ON c.IDN = d.IDN AND d.Flag_av='1'

            Where  a.IDN='$active'  
        ");
```

So as you can see change only table (from offer to user) and condition (Where), but is it possible to make it in one Select? As double select I thought about UNION since if the IDN will be in two table the row can repeat and I don't need it. But again I would like to have it in one Select. Is it possible?

Comment: the UNION does not must repeat.. if select 1 union select 2 the identical rows does not must repeat (if the query result row is distinct do you will have 2 rows), UNION ALL must repeat

Comment: Yes, it was I mean the union will not show double rows, and it is ok, the question is how to make a one select from this two.

Comment: if you have.. select x,1 from A where P UNION select x,2 from B where Q. do you have 2 rows for the same "Row" and you can see as 2 rows.. and by the 1 or 2 you can know the source

Comment: Well as I sad I'm not interested in UNION, I figured it by my self please take a look

Comment: seems good your answer

Comment: well I think so but I think I can optimize it better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out by my self, since user table have all users I will take all row from them with more complex condition. The first tests got good. If you see mistake or have a better variant please share ))) THANKS.

```
        $result =mysql_query("
            SELECT a.IDN, c.Name_F, c.Name_L, d.Url_photo, 
                    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                        FROM Messages AS e
                        WHERE   e.IDN = a.IDN               
                    ) AS 'mes_new' ,
                    ( SELECT LEFT(s.Messages,25)
                        FROM Messages AS s
                        WHERE s.Time= (SELECT MAX(k.Time)
                        FROM Messages AS k
                        WHERE k.IDN = a.IDN)

                    ) AS latest 
            FROM users AS a 
                    LEFT JOIN offers AS r
                ON a.IDN = r.IDN 
                    LEFT JOIN info AS c
                ON a.IDN = c.IDN
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN photos AS d
                ON c.IDN = d.IDN AND d.Flag_av='1'

            Where (r.IDN_with='$IDN' AND r.Status='2') OR a.IDN='$active'       
        ");
```